# 20 days prior to 1st of October, 2018 ("Pandas")

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandoc, eof

There is a case am working since 2 days to solve the following issue:

```
end_Date = "1st October, 2018"
end_Date = pd.to_datetime(end_Date)
start_Date = end_Date - pd.Timedelta(days = 20)

df360[(df360.claim_date <= str(end_Date)) & (df360.claim_date >= str(start_Date))['claim_amount'].sum()
```

**while I do this:**
I get the following error

> File "<ipython-input-44-1a6629fd9584>", line 1
>       df360[(df360.claim_date <= str(end_Date)) & (df360.claim_date >= str(start_Date))['claim_amount'].sum()
>                                                                                                              ^
>   SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: split it to smaller parts - variables - to see if you didn't forget `()` or `[]`

Comment: Now I see you have opening `[` in `df360[` but you don't have closing `]` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code with `.loc`

```
df360.claim_date = pd.to_datetime(df360.claim_date)
df360.loc[(df360.claim_date <= end_Date) & (df360.claim_date >= start_Date),'claim_amount'].sum()
```

Comment: Done i got it! Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 0):

## I've did it in jupyter notebook:

```
end_Date = "1st October, 2018"
end_Date = pd.to_datetime(end_Date)
start_Date = end_Date - pd.Timedelta(days = 20)
```

Then:

```
df360['claim_amount'].dtypes
```

See whether you get this as output:

> dtype('float64')

and not:

> dtype('o')

then paste this code:

```
df360[(df360.claim_date <= end_Date) & (df360.claim_date >= start_Date)]['claim_amount'].sum()
```

### i get the output successfully! & thanks for the help!